# How do I pass the forest stage on Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I cannot pass the forest stage on Candy Box 2. The dogs and forest mosquitos kill me fast.

My stats and equipment are:

- 220 health
- Polished silver sword (7 damage, also have the trolls bludgeon; 12-16 damage)
- Leather boots and gloves (no stat bonus)
- Basic and advanced spells from the witch across the bridge

On another save I also increased my health to 1000 and still could not pass the forest stage, any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enchant your gloves by throwing chocolate bars into the well. Pink gloves are great for the forest (they give you health regen). Also, you should kill the monkey wizard in the cave for a better weapon. Enchanting and using his staff should make the forest level easy, especially if you already have 220 health.

The forest is a roadblock at first but if you can clear out the cave it'll be easy.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found was

- Pink enchanted gloves
- Grab the Grimoires from the hut
- Beating the OKtopus King is then doable without any potions, enchant the crown with Obsidian
- Use this to beat the Monkey Wizard (it's really hard and longwinded without the obsidian crown because he always runs away)

Then the Forrest becomes a cake walk!

Answer (score 1):

- Get the crown from the Octopus King, enchant it with jaspers -- this will increase your damage.
- Get the staff from the Monkey Wizard, enchant it, this will massively increase your damage.
- Give your gloves the pink enchantment.

To kill the Octopus King, you'll probably need health potions. This means investing some time in the lollipop farming to get 100,000 lollipops and buy if from the Sorceress.

Answer (score 1):

1. Eat more candies.
2. Go to the ocean and get the sponge.
3. Go to the forest, squeeze, then jump everywhere.

Comment: Just a note: To get the jump ability you need to get the Pogo stick which is located to the right of 'the cave'. Look for a * within the mountains.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the forest within 10 minutes of the game starting.

1. Get chocolate bar and enchant pink gloves.
2. Farm Troll for 2000 candies
3. Get Silver Sword, pogo stick, 5000 lollipop grimoire, desert bird feather
4. Kill Octopus King:  use jump and teleport to avoid octopus when you need to regen hp, it takes about a minute.  Enchant his crown with Obsidian.
5. Kill the wizard, enchant his staff
6. Clear forest.

Answer (score 1):

- Enchant gloves to pink
- Kill *Octopus King* for crown enchant obsidian
- Kill *Monkey Wizard* for staff enchant
- Clear the forest