# How do I progress more?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have been farming for a LONG TIME now on Candy Box 2... But I can't figure out how to progress. I have been stuck with the Trolls bludgeon and I can't find anything stronger. I can't enchant it or anything, and I can't get past the Forest because of it! There is NOTHING I can do to get past it! Anyone know how to get more weapons?

Comment: [The answers to this question should help you get past the forest](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137370/how-do-i-pass-the-forest-stage-on-candy-box-2)

Comment: Have you found chocolate bars? Have you tried the cave? How about the forge? Have you been to the sorceress’ hut? Have you gotten the cauldron and created some potions? Have you gotten the time-slowing ring and the gloves and boots?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes yes yes yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to get the pogo stick which is obtained by

> clicking the * near the cave entrance

Then, if you dont have the armor already, get it. It is gotten by going to the forge with 15 thousand candies, which Im pretty sure its buyable after you beat the troll

An easy way to get the candies necessary is to boost your lollipop farm to maximum (100) and throwing those lollipops in the wishing well for candies.

You could also grind out the troll for candies.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Farm the troll, go to the well and upgrade if you have chocolate bars, and plant lollies at the lolly farm