# When will the forge have new weapons availible?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have already bought the lightweight armor from the forge. He said to come back later, so I came back on today, but that message is still there. The forest is very difficult, so I need some new weapon. When will he be back in stock?

Comment: I have answered your stated question below.  For what you're actually after, try here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137370/how-do-i-pass-the-forest-stage-on-candy-box-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, items appear in the forge when you have enough candies to purchase them.  However, the next item is the

> Scythe

which actually unlocks

> once you have reached the castle and spoken to the dragon *and* sufficient candies,

so not until after the forest.